# Spark SQL source data locality

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have a HDFS cluster on 3 nodes, with replication factor 3. So all data is local on each node. On the *same* nodes, 3 Spark Executors run (the driver runs elsewhere). When I verify the Spark Task Locality level after running a few SQL queries, I would expect to see all Tasks to have `NODE_LOCAL` locality. However, I see 1/3 of the tasks on `NODE_LOCAL` and 2/3 on `ANY`. I have a hard time understanding this.

Specifically, what I want to measure is the locality level of the tasks that actually fetch the HDFS data (in contrast with the locality level of *all* tasks). Starting from a Spark events file I filter the tasks that are part of a Stage which is part of a `spark.sql.execution`.

```
stages = df.filter("Event='SparkListenerJobStart'").filter(col("Properties.`spark.sql.execution.id`").isNotNull())
result = df.filter("Event='SparkListenerTaskEnd'").select(... "Task Info.Locality", "Stage ID", ...).join(stages, "Stage ID")
```

When I compare the `Locality` level of the `result` DataFrame, I see the 1/3 ratio.

When I print the [preferred locations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#preferredLocations(split:org.apache.spark.Partition):Seq%5BString%5D) of each partition of the RDD, all partitions list all 3 nodes (which is correct as data is replicated on all machines). I notice these prefered locations are listed by their hostname. On the other hand, in the Spark UI executors are listed by IP, so I wonder if this is a reason for confusion on Spark's side when assigning locality labels on Spark jobs.